# How to check property is required or not in Joi

Tags: node.js, npm, option-type, required, joi

I want to assign required to either `client_id` or `client_secret` I have to check in Joi if one of these property is not empty assign it `required`
`Joi` how can i check this

```
schema = Joi.Object().keys({
    account_id: Joi.string().required(),
    client_id: Joi.string(),   // in client_id or client_secret //
    client_secret: Joi.string() // one must be required I have to check for This in Joi
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `object.or` to resolve this issue

```
schema = Joi.Object().keys({
    account_id: Joi.string().required(),
    client_id: Joi.string(),   // in client_id or client_secret //
    client_secret: Joi.string() // one must be required I have to check for This in Joi
}).or('client_id', 'client_secret');
```